# Limit HTTP method on ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: iptables, firewall, ubuntu-12.04, ufw

For starters, this is not a web server.  I would like to allow or deny HTTP methods on various ports on the server itself.

Ideally could write rules like UFW only extended to include the HTTP method

e.g.

```
ufw allow 80 -method GET -deny POST,PUT,DELETE
```

Is there any lightweight solution to this?

Thank you.  The servers typically run products such as elasticsearch, redis, etc. and It would be great to only allow those operations from certain IP's on their various ports.

Answer (score 1):

The default Linux netfilter firewall is a packet filter, so that's not going to help you much.

What you're looking for is what's typically called a layer 7 firewall, an application firewall that understands the HTTP protocol.

Alternatively look at an IPS. I think you can for instance configure SNORT to run inline, doing real time packet inspection.